# Connect to AzureBlobStorage from AzureServiceFabric stateless service

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, azure-service-fabric, azure-blob-storage, service-fabric-stateless

I have a stateless service running on Service Fabric, it's behind a corporate proxy.
I'm trying to connect to Azure to upload some images to blob storage, but is not working. Is it possible to set Service Fabric proxy or maybe there are other solutions ?

When I'm trying to upload a image :

```
await blob.UploadFromStreamAsync(fileStream);
```

Exception thrown:

```
InnerException = {System.Net.Http.WinHttpException (0x80072EE2): The 
operation timed out
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
at System.Threading.Tasks.RendezvousAwaitable`1.GetResult()
at System.Net.Http.WinHttpHandler.<StartRequest...
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate on 'is not working' part?

Comment: Can you upload it from the local machine or with a hosted ASP application?

Comment: This shouldn't be any different from running a console application to upload it - can you try with a simple console app first?